# Listing geo-places near a user location

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, geolocation

I have a php webapp that allows people to insert their location via google maps api (v3). I then store the lat/lng coordinates to my db.

Another thing I do is allow people to add certain events to a database, I then insert the event to my db with the same lat/lng of the user. for example:

Users table:

```
ID    U_Name    U_Location_ID
1     test      23
```

Events table:

```
ID    E_Name    E_Location_ID
1     testevent 23
```

Location table:

```
ID    L_LAT        L_LNG        L_Name
23    40.759139    -73.979723   30 Rockefeller Plaza, New York, NY 10112, USA
```

What I'm trying to do now, is to display a user with a list of events that are **near** his location.

I don't necessarily have his exact location, but usually just the country and city (not all visitors are registered members that filled in their exact location).

So when a member vists, I use an ip to location api that gives me his country name and city name. I have another way of getting the country/city lat/lng coordinates, but now I'm stuck when I need to display the near events to that city/country.

When I say 'near' I hope it's possible to set some sort of diameter in Kilometers or Miles and list the events that are within that diameter.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here the full query in MySQL that works on every tables. Keep in mind that the lat / lon fields must be decimal fields, unless you will loose precision :

```
-- set your vars
SET @lat := $$$$$;
SET @lon := $$$$$;
SET @dist := $$$$$;

-- prepare a square in miles
SET @x1 := @lon - @dist / ABS(COS(RADIANS(@lat))*69);
SET @x2 := @lon + @dist / ABS(COS(RADIANS(@lat))*69);
SET @y1 := @lat - (@dist / 69);
SET @y2 := @lat + (@dist / 69);

SELECT  t.*, 
        3956 * 2 * ASIN(
            SQRT(
                POWER(
                    SIN(
                        (@lat - t.lat) * pi() / 180 / 2
                    ), 2
                ) +
                COS(
                    @lat * pi() / 180
                ) *
                COS(
                    t.lat * pi() / 180
                ) *
                POWER(
                    SIN(
                        (@lon - t.lon) * pi() / 180 / 2
                    ), 2
                )
            )
        ) as distance
FROM    `YourTable` t
WHERE   t.longitude BETWEEN @x1 AND @x2
AND     t.latitude BETWEEN @y1 AND @y2
HAVING  distance < @dist
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10;
```

You just need to replace the `$$$$$` with your values. 
Now if you want a full explanation, see this [slides by Alexander Rubin](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)

And for kilometers, just replace the `x1`, `x2` ... by

```
-- prepare a square or in kilometers
SET @x1 := @lon - @dist / ABS(COS(RADIANS(@lat))*110);
SET @x2 := @lon + @dist / ABS(COS(RADIANS(@lat))*110);
SET @y1 := @lat - (@dist / 110);
SET @y2 := @lat + (@dist / 110);
```

Comment: How is @dist defined? kilometers?

Comment: Currently in miles. I've updated my post to show how to request within kilometers.

Comment: When I try running this query through mysql_query() I'm getting an error, do you have any idea why?

Comment: try one query per `;`, like this : `mysql_query('SET @lat := $$$$$'); mysql_query('SET @ lon := $$$$$'); ...`

Comment: @XavierBarbosa can you please look at Britton comment please and thanks for your wonderful answer

Comment: @XavierBarbosa the as distance is returning the distance in km right if we use And for kilometers, just replace the x1, x2 ... by and also what should be type of lat and long fileds in our database. Thansk in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its important to note that if you go with the wonderful answer by Xavier --and-- if you use his kilometers change you must also change 3956 * 2 to 6371 * 2 in the calculation or you're just changing the range, not the produced distance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understanding your problem. If you are using geolocation DB like MaxMind, you also get to every city a latitude/longititude. You just have to choose some delta for longitude and latitude, run the SQL query and calculate in your view the distance from the users location to the event location. It's not really complicated.

Comment: What is the correct calculation for the LAT/LNG? If this is my LAT/LNG: 40.759139/-73.979723 and I want to SELECT from the mysql DB all events that are within a 50KM distance from that LAT/LNG, how do I perform that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of [mysql spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query wich could help you get all locations within a certain diameter. {NUMBER OF KILOMETERS} will be the diameter. $lon AND $lat will bet the coordinates of the users' location.

`SELECT 
    D.*,
    DEGREES(acos(cos(RADIANS(90-latitude))*cos(RADIANS(90-$lat))+sin(RADIANS(90-latitude))*sin(RADIANS(90-$lat))*cos(RADIANS(longitude-$lon))))/360*40074 
AS 
    distance 
FROM 
    location_table as D
HAVING 
    distance <= {NUMBER OF KILOMETERS}`